# Appending to h5py groups

Tags: python, python-2.7, hdf5, h5py

I have files with the following structure:

- time 1
- index 1
- value x
- value y
- time 1
- index 2
- value x
- value y
- time 2
- index 1
- ...

I wish to convert the file to the hdf5 format using h5py, and sort the values from each index into separate groups.

My approach is

```
f = h5py.File(filename1,'a')
trajfile = open(filename2, 'rb')

    for i in range(length_of_filw):
        time = struct.unpack('>d', filename2.read(8))[0]
        index = struct.unpack('>i', filename2.read(4))[0]       
        x = struct.unpack('>d', filename2.read(8))[0]
        y = struct.unpack('>d', filename2.read(8))[0]

        f.create_dataset('/'+str(index), data=[time,x,y,z])
```

But in this way I am not able to append to the groups (I am only able to write to each group once...). The error message is "RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)".

Is there a way to append to the groups?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* write to a dataset as many times as you want - you just can't have twice a dataset with the same name. This is the error you're getting. Note that you are creating a dataset and at the same time you are putting some data inside of it. In order to write other data to it, it has to be large enough to accomodate it.

Anyway, I believe you are confusing groups and datasets.
Groups are created with e.g.

```
grp = f.create_group('bar') # this create the group '/bar'
```

and you want to store datasets in a dataset, created like you said with:

```
dst = f.create_dataset('foo',shape=(100,)) # this create the dataset 'foo', with enough space for 100 elements.
```

you only need to create groups and datasets once - but you can refer to them through their handles, (grp and dst), in order to write in them.

I suggest you first go through your file once, create your desired groups and datasets using the 'shape' parameter to properly size it, and then populate the datasets with actual data.